# How to access the DJIGO app flight Plan log files

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, dji-sdk

I want to access the DJI-Go App Flight Plan log files similar to [HealthyDrones App](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hd-sync/id1119446353?mt=8) ( [website for more about it](https://healthydrones.com/sync-app) ). This app verifies the DJI login credentials in their app But In DJI SDK Documentation there no information about integrating DJI-Login and accessing the log files.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing the flight log files is not supported and undocumented.  You can search the mobile device file system (depending on which DJI app you want to support) and find the file path for the log files but this can be changed by DJI at any time.

The format itself is also undocumented, meaning DJI can change or update the format at any time and break any apps that have reverse engineered the log files.

HD and a few others have decoded the files and you could contact then to see if they will share the information they found but as for finding a "supported" method to access the log files, it does not exist today.